# How do I use a section counter inside a tcblisting?

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, minted, tcblisting

I'd like to add the current figure/section number to the title of a `tcblisting`. Right now, my hacky solution is to just use the section number and increment it manually every time I want to use my `tcblisting`. Is there any way to have it automatically increment (or, even better, make it reference the deepest section, e.g., if I'm in subsubsection 3, it should be labeled as "1.1.3").

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mylisting}[section]
\renewcommand{\themylisting}{\thesection.\arabic{mylisting}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[minted,skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{MySchemeListing}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    frame hidden, 
    borderline north = {1pt}{0pt}{black},
    borderline south = {1pt}{0pt}{black},
    opacityfill=0,
    listing only,
    title={\textcolor{black}{Listing \themylisting---#2\ifstrempty{#1}{}{~(\texttt{#1})}}},
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-3.55mm,yshift=-0.4mm},
    boxed title style={frame hidden,colback=black!0!white},
    minted language=scheme,
    minted options={autogobble},
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}

\refstepcounter{mylisting}
\begin{MySchemeListing}[main.rkt]{Fibonacci code example in Racket}
    ;; ! : Number -> Number 
    ;; Computes the factorial of a number.
    ;; (define ! ...)
    (define !
      (lambda (n)
        (cond
          [(zero? n) 1]
          [else (* n (! (- n 1)))])))
\end{MySchemeListing}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `auto counter, number within=section`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[minted,skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting[auto counter, number within=section]{MySchemeListing}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    frame hidden, 
    borderline north = {1pt}{0pt}{black},
    borderline south = {1pt}{0pt}{black},
    opacityfill=0,
    listing only,
    title={\textcolor{black}{Listing \thetcbcounter---#2\ifstrempty{#1}{}{~(\texttt{#1})}}},
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-3.55mm,yshift=-0.4mm},
    boxed title style={frame hidden,colback=black!0!white},
    minted language=scheme,
    minted options={autogobble},
}

\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
    
    \begin{MySchemeListing}[main.rkt]{Fibonacci code example in Racket}
        ;; ! : Number -> Number 
        ;; Computes the factorial of a number.
        ;; (define ! ...)
        (define !
        (lambda (n)
        (cond
        [(zero? n) 1]
        [else (* n (! (- n 1)))])))
    \end{MySchemeListing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a deeper numbering

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[minted,skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting[auto counter, number within=subsubsection]{MySchemeListing}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    frame hidden, 
    borderline north = {1pt}{0pt}{black},
    borderline south = {1pt}{0pt}{black},
    opacityfill=0,
    listing only,
    title={\textcolor{black}{Listing \thetcbcounter---#2\ifstrempty{#1}{}{~(\texttt{#1})}}},
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-3.55mm,yshift=-0.4mm},
    boxed title style={frame hidden,colback=black!0!white},
    minted language=scheme,
    minted options={autogobble},
}

\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
    
    \begin{MySchemeListing}[main.rkt]{Fibonacci code example in Racket}
        ;; ! : Number -> Number 
        ;; Computes the factorial of a number.
        ;; (define ! ...)
        (define !
        (lambda (n)
        (cond
        [(zero? n) 1]
        [else (* n (! (- n 1)))])))
    \end{MySchemeListing}
\end{document}
```

[image]